# Mongoid Delete Document matching ID

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I'm trying to remove a duplicate document in my collection. Here's my code:

```
class Sites
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: "sites"
end

Sites.destroy_all(conditions: { _id: BSON::ObjectId("5685a45be4b06ab5911dcd12")})
```

Here's what is returned:

```
D, [2015-12-31T17:39:16.488657 #10126] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | rails.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"sites", "filter"=>{"conditions"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5685a45be4b06ab5911dcd12')}}}
D, [2015-12-31T17:39:16.488946 #10126] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | rails.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.000189083s
```

But when I search the document is still there :(

```
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5685a45be4b06ab5911dcd12'), "name"=>"StackOverflow", "title"=>"Stack Overflow", "type"=>"Forum", "url"=>"http://www.stackoverflow.com"}
```

**How do I permanently delete a document by reference using Mongoid?**

Answer (score 10):

Mongoid with 5.x follows a lot more closely to the AR methods we are used to so your id field is behaves in a similar way.

```
Sites.where(id: '5685a45be4b06ab5911dcd12').delete
```

To have all the necessary callbacks be called as well just use `.destroy`. Just know this loads everything into memory and can be expensive.

```
Sites.where(id: '5685a45be4b06ab5911dcd12').destroy
```

Answer (score 2):

After doing a lot of iterations this works for me:

```
Sites.destroy_all({ :_id => BSON::ObjectId('5685a45be4b06ab5911dcd12')})
```

I've found that Mongoid is not very helpful when troubleshooting. I have to do a lot more trial and error to discover how to do things :(

Comment: `{ :_id => BSON::ObjectId('5685a45be4b06ab5911dcd12')}` and `{ _id: BSON::ObjectId('5685a45be4b06ab5911dcd12')}` resolve to the exact same hash AFAIK.